# Extract QoS control value from .pcap file

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, pcap, qos

I need to implement .pcap parser for QoS values analyzing. 
The problem is to open .pcap-file (generated by Wireshark or tcpdump) and **extract QoS Control value** (if available) from each package.
 I know that **QoS Control** located inside **IEEE 802.11 QoS Data** layer (it's available through Wireshark), but I have no idea how to extract this parameter from my script.
I've tried to use:
1. Python + dpkt 
2. C# + sharppcap 
and I've got data from IP and TCP layers, but without any data about QoS.

Probably, I need to explore raw .pcap and look for QoS data without any parsers, but maybe it's available another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tshark command (part of Wireshark), you can extract one or more fields in text format. Example command:

```
tshark -r some.pcap -Tfields -e wlan.qos
```

You can find the `wlan.qos` field at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/w/wlan.html. To find the field name for fields you see in Wireshark, select the field and look in the status bar for the name and description.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful!